# Howler audio seek always returns 0

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I want to get the progress of a sound played by using the howler library.

The seek() function always returns 0 for me.

First I initialize the sound:

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['Audio/Track.wav']
});
```

Then I play the sound from another function (i can hear the sound) and try to get the seek.

```
function update() {    
   requestAnimationFrame(update);

    if(!audioIsPlaying){
        sound.play();
        audioIsPlaying = true;
    }

    let seek = sound.seek || 0;
    console.log(formatTime(Math.round(seek)));    
}

function formatTime(secs) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60) || 0;
    var seconds = (secs - minutes * 60) || 0;

    return minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
}
```

Any ideas?

Greets

Answer (score 1):

instead of `let seek = sound.seek || 0;`

write `let seek = sound.seek() || 0;`

seek is a function, not a property